# how to load a menu when we click an item in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a view there it is displaying address information about the client. when I clcik Edit contact then new view should appear . how  to do that?
 here is my code.

```
<div ng-show="addressBook">    
    <div ng-repeat="names in addressBookNames()">       
        <div ng-show="addressId === names.idNo">
             <div class="inboxTabs">
            <div class="basicTab appFont" ng-click="edit=== true">Edit Contact</div>
            <div class="basicTab appFont"> Delete Contact</div>           
             </div>
           <h3> <center>{{names.firstName}},{{names.lastName}} </center></h3>
          <table style="width:60%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Organization</th>
                        <th>Role/Specialty</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{names.organization}}</td>
                        <td>{{names.roleSpecialty}}</td>
                        <td>{{names.id}}</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>License/Certificates</th>
                        <th>Affiliations</th>
                        <th>Insurance Accepted</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{names.licenses}}</td>
                        <td>{{names.Affiliations}}</td>
                        <td>{{names.InsuranceAccepteds}}</td>
                    </tr>
             </table>
</div>
</div>
```

here, when I click Edit contact another view should display on the same place where address details are showing.

Comment: Please edit the code to be readable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, `ng-if` should be your friend

Basically with ng-if you can render a part of your view in dependent on some variable.

For Example in your controller:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myController', function() {
    $scope.edit = false;

    /*
     * set edit to true if its false
     * set edit to false if its true
     */
    var setEditable = function() {
        if ($scope.edit === false) {
            $scope.edit = true;
            // possible place for saving actions
        } else {
            $scope.edit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

in your view:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-if="edit">
     I Am only shown if edit === true;
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!edit">
     I Am only shown if edit === false;
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` but i would recommend the usage of `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-show="edit">
        I Am only shown if edit === true;
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="edit">
        I Am only shown if edit === false;
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can create a function in ng-click and every time u execute that function u can push new object to the whatever the array u are ng-repeating

```
<div class="basicTab appFont" ng-click="NewForm()">Edit Contact</div>
```

inside controller

```
$scope.NewForm = function(){
 $scope.TestArray.push({ //array 
     firstName:'',
     lastName:'',
     organization:'',
     roleSpecialty:'',
     id:''     // likewise add the rest of the elements 
})
}
```